# How can I recover MediaWiki pages from an old MAMP install?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, mamp

I have a three year old or so MAMP install (a copy of the application folder and all its contents, databases, etc.) with a three year old MediWiki (version 1.19) installed on it, several pages, and a few images.  I would like to know how I can access those pages (or at least the content on them) and import them or copy them over to a fresh install I made today with the latest versions of MAMP and MediaWiki.

I already tried copying the database folder (MAMP/db/mysql/my_database; contains .frm files) from the old install to the same location in the new install but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.  I even looked at the contents of the tables with phpMyAdmin but I didn't find any of the old content.  Where do I go from here?

I installed MAMP on my MacBook Pro running OSX Yosemite.  I'm hosting locally (e.g. using `localhost`).  I am able to install a fresh MediaWiki on my localhost MAMP server and it works fine (there's just no content).

UPDATE: After seeing [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/cannot_upgrade_to_1.18_from_1.17_-_APC_issue) I changed `$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ACCEL` to `$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ANYTHING` in the MediaWiki local settings file and now I get an error page that looks like this:

[image]

Do I need to somehow upgrade my databases?  They are old after all.  How should I go about doing this?

Comment: It's the same server - just localhost.  In fact I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown mysql

Just copying the MAMP/db/mysql/my_database is not enough

Copy the contents of your db folder and below to the new
MAMP db folder

Note i assume your new MAMP is pretty virgin

Poached it from here :

http://joejoomla.com/sound-off/157-how-to-upgrade-mamp.html

Start new mysql

Will incl necessary config files

It is not as if you should have expected MAMP to recurse directories

It needs config files from old and you don't have them yet

I have never done it on MAMP

---

Edit:
Concerning warning that resulted

Make sure that XCache is installed with the new version of PHP. The most likely cause is the new version of PHP simply doesn't have xcache installed. You can do this by creating a php file with just the code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and then viewing it in a web browser.

Setting $wgMainCacheType = `CACHE_NONE`; will disable all caching, which would prevent the error, but make things slow.

From: http://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/%22CACHE_ACCEL_requested_but_no_suitable_object_cache_is_present.%22

Comment: Okay I restored the databases with the servers off and ran it again - I got the following error: 

`CACHE_ACCEL requested but no suitable object cache is present. You may want to install APC.

Backtrace:

#0 [internal function]: ObjectCache::newAccelerator(Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/life/includes/objectcache/ObjectCache.php(62): call_user_func('ObjectCache::ne...', Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/life/includes/objectcache/ObjectCache.php(50): ObjectCache::newFromParams(Array)
#3 ` ...

Comment: I tried both of those things.  The new php file just gives me a bunch of information about the PHP version I have installed, and setting `$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE` didn't appear to affect anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: That is what that php file is meant to do and show u modules and settings. Can u connect to db? is mamp working as expected? I was pointing you to articles avail thru google. You have 1 advantage over me in solving any mamp-related issues. You have a mamp server (i dont)

Answer (score 1):

Advice : for this kind of software, use a Virtual Machine, it will save your time : my own mediawiki is running for 8 years under debian, hosted on a several different Apple machines.

But for now, if you still have the former stack running :

0 . (always) save your database content + files

- for the database :
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnOE0KWHGkY
- for the files :
  tar cfvz my-old-mediawiki.tar.gz path-to-mediawiki-directory

> This will allow you to rollback if something goes wrong

1. Export your content and history

   - go to the special page : "Export pages", list your pages.
   - if needed, use the special page : "List all pages".

> this will produce an xml file.

2. Save your images somewhere on your file system

   - use the special page : "List all files".

> you now have exported your pages and files

3) Switch stack

> check that the new virgin mediawiki is working well

4. import your pages

   - go to the special page : "import pages", upload the xml file produced in step 1

> you now have a similar wiki, minus the files

5. import your images :

   - after the step 4, each file page has been created without its content.
   - you can upload manually each image exported at step 2) if you have only some of them,
   - if that is too much files (>30), you can use this procedure : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php

> keep in mind also to reinstall any extensions installed previously.

Comment: So I actually just have a backup of the files as they were used on MAMP previously.  I wish I could run the old server and back things up correctly, but I don't think I can.  Is there a way I can add the files and databased I have to a fresh MAMP install and access them?  Perhaps to create a backup I can import somewhere else?

Comment: to backup is mostly a good practice to recover in case of failure during the update process.  And it is also a best practice to use a copy of the back up to test your migration elsewhere than in your current install. So, yes, if you have another MacOsX computer, you can copy your previous install, make it run, replace your old files with new version of mediawiki and make it work. When you know how to update, redo the process on your main install.     but I assume it is too late for you now :( see my next comment

Comment: for now, export the database and images (the WHOLE directory).  Install a fresh MAMP + a fresh mediawiki. Overwrite DB and image directory with previous one. run php script for update (in /maintenance) . Cross fingers.